# Counter-example to: if $f^{-1}(f(X))= X$, then f is injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The full question is:
Given a function $f:A\rightarrow B$, prove that:
$f$ is injective if and only if $f^{-1}(f(X))= X$ for all $X \subset A$

I initially was thinking:
If $f^{-1}(f(X))= X$, then $x \in f^{-1}(f(X))= X \iff x \in X$

But then I thought:
What if there are $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ in X, with $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$ and $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$?

Then $f$ isn't injective and $f^{-1}(f(X))= X$ still seems valid.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This has to work for all $X \subset A$ right? What about the case where $X = \{x_1\}$?

Comment: I understand that if there is only $x_{1}$ in X and $f$ isn't injective then there could be an element of Y, such that $Y\subset f^{-1}(f(X))$ and $f^{-1}(f(X))\neq X$. But my question is what if there are two elements in X, and the function of both have the value?

Comment: This has answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78110/is-f-1fa-a-always-true.

Comment: @MateusBarbosa make sure you understand what the quantifier 'for all' means

Comment: I think I got it. Is it because in my example there could be $X=\left\lbrace x_{1},x_{2}\right\rbrace $ and $Y=\left\lbrace x_{1}\right\rbrace $ with $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$  and then, even though $Y \subset A$, $f^{-1}(f(Y))\neq Y$

Comment: @MateusBarbosa: It has to work for **all** subsets $X$ of $A$. If there are $x_1,x_2\in A$ such that $x_1\ne x_2$, but $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $$f^{-1}\big[f[\{x_1\}]\big]\supseteq\{x_1,x_2\}\ne\{x_1\}\;,$$ and it does not work for $X=\{x_1\}$. It also fails for $X=\{x_2\}$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you all very much.

Comment: You may have understood "for all $X\subset A$" as applying to the whole statement "$f$ is injective if and only if $f^{-1}(f(X))=X$", but the person who wrote it intended "for all $X\subset A$" to apply only to the last part, "$f^{-1}(f(X))=X$", I'm inclined to blame the author for this ambiguity. It won't confuse experienced mathematicians who know what should be meant, but it's likely to confuse students who are just learning this material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no counter-example.  Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.  Then $x_1=f^{-1}f(x_1)=f^{-1}f(x_2)=x_2$.  Thus $f$ is injective.